# AI 100 Convert speech from an audio file to text

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-search

I am doing this lesson Convert speech from an audio file to text from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/transcribe-speech-input-text/5-exercise-convert-speech-from-audio-file?pivots=python

When I executed this command pip install --upgrade azure-cognitiveservices-speech in VisualStudio Code, I am getting this error given below.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azure-cognitiveservices-speech

I've no clue as how to fix these errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even with the command pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech

Comment: your python version? because maybe it demands python 3.5 /3.6

Comment: I am on Python 3.9.0 64 bit and visual studio code 1.5.1.1

Comment: Step down your python to 3.5 preferably .. and than try installation.

Comment: I've installed Python 3.5.3 64 bit and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Problem is not azure-cognitiveservices-speech, the problem is your dotnet or visual studio code

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python see the steps if you have all on board

Answer (score 0):

Even the following commands are not working in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/transcribe-speech-input-text/7-optional-exercise-listen-incoming-data. Looks like some thing is wrong with the Visual Studio Code that I am using. Would appreciate if any one can help me fix these issues.

PS C:\Users\I814150\OneDrive - SAP SE\AI100\microphoneinput.py> dotnet new console
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- dotnet new console
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotnet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\I814150\OneDrive - SAP SE\AI100\microphoneinput.py> dotnet add package Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- dotnet add package Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotnet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```